# SQL Transaction and View

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is:

> Increase the book_limit by 2 for all members, but the maximum limit is 10. Display the member ID
>   and limit for each member before and after you make the changes.
>
> *No views can be created and the query needs to be one, not a series of multiple queries.
>
> *(All needed fields are in the same table called Member)

What I have so far :

```
SET book_limit = CASE
WHEN book_limit >= 10 THEN book_limit*1
WHEN book_limit = 9 THEN book_limit+1
ELSE book_limit+2
end;
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj27781.html) function?

Comment: You need to query your table, update the table, and then query it again... all in a single query? And what does your title mean? Anyway... what are you actually asking? What is your full statement at the moment and what is wrong with it?

Comment: yes I can use MAX function

Comment: I meant to ask if it can be written in a single query, I used limit as a constraint and used cases in the final submission, sorry for the inappropriate title

Answer (score 0):

Display unmodified table, modify table based on the logic you have in place,
display updated table:

```
SELECT memberID, book_limit FROM Member; 

SET book_limit = CASE
WHEN book_limit >= 10 THEN book_limit*1
WHEN book_limit = 9 THEN book_limit+1
ELSE book_limit+2
end;

SELECT memberID, book_limit FROM Member;
```